# Pulling values from an array based on date?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, time

I have an array of data points, `[date, value]`, like so...

```
data_points = [[1310279340, 1], [1310279340, 1]]
```

I need to create an array based on "milliseconds ago", with ten values for each second, or a value for every 100ms going backwards.

The new array's values will look like, `[ms ago, value]`, like so...

```
ms_ago_points = [[0,3],[100,6],[200,7]]
```

So the last value in that array represents [200ms ago, value of 7].

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get "value from Xms ago" based on date values in the first array. If needed I might be able to get the initial date/values in a format other then an array if it would be easier to poll for data.

Thanks for any guidance!!

edit:  I'm looking to repeat the same value between dates for every 100ms tick that lands between them.

Comment: while loops, filtering through the array of dates and trying to separate values out on a 100ms gap but it got messy quick and i had no luck getting it to work

Comment: maybe getting the date/values in a structure other then an array could help?

Comment: What does this number `1310279340` mean? How is it a date? Assuming that they are dates somehow, I take it that you need to form an interpolated "line". Are you looking for a slope between data points or just repeating the last known value between dates? Since the dates presumably aren't on exact 100 ms intervals, what do you want to do if (for example) there are multiple dates in the same 100 ms--average them out? This is not clear at all. A detailed example would be most, most helpful.

Comment: @ErikE It's unix time. I'm looking to repeat the same value between dates for every 100ms tick that lands between them.

Comment: How do you get the current time in JavaScript into a number representing Unix time?

Comment: @ErikE `Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)` would do it. That data is being sent to me from an API though, I'm not creating it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it was in seconds, not ms. Okay.

Comment: One more thing--is the data_points array sorted?

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = Date.now(),
    l = data_points.length,
    ms_ago_points = [];

for ( var c = 0; c < l; c++ ) {
  ms_ago_points.push([now - data_points[c][0],data_points[c][1]);
}
```

Maybe you need to sort the `ms_ago_points` afterwards, but this should give you your desired array.
**However**: I'd seriously suggest you not to work with multi-dimesional arrays but objects instead:

```
ms_ago_points= [{ms: 0, value: 3},{ms:100, value: 6}...]
```

*edit: This of course assumes that your `data_points` are already in 100ms steps, otherwise you'd have to implement an interpolation :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this meets your requirements:

```
function msFromDataPoints(nowTime, dataPoints) {
    var d = dataPoints.length,
        i = 0,
        anchor = Math.floor(nowTime.getTime() / 100) * 100,
        ms = anchor,
        msArr = [];
    while (d--) {
        while (ms >= data_points[d][0] * 1000) {
            msArr.push([anchor - ms, dataPoints[d][1]];
            ms -= 100;
        }
    }
    return msArr;
}
```

See it in a [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErikE/52Dgc/).

Note: I find the data structures to be a little strange. An object for the input seems best:

```
[{date: 1310279340, value: 1}, {date: 1310279340, value: 1}]
```

And your output array doesn't need the milliseconds at all, as simply `[1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 2 4]` (or whatever) would be understood to mean millisecond indexes starting at 0 and increasing by 100. If absolutely required, you could use a sparse array:

```
result = [];
result[0] = 1;
result[100] = 1;
result[200] = 5; // and so on
```